# Converting XML file into CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have an `XML` file which looks like this:

```
<Organism>
 <Name>Bacillus halodurans C-125</Name>
  <Enzyme>M.BhaII</Enzyme>
   <Motif>GGCC</Motif>
  <Enzyme>M1.BhaI</Enzyme>
   <Motif>GCATC</Motif>
  <Enzyme>M2.BhaI</Enzyme>
   <Motif>GCATC</Motif>
</Organism>
<Organism>
 <Name>Bacteroides eggerthii 1_2_48FAA</Name>
</Organism>
```

I'm trying to write it into a `CSV` file like this:

```
Bacillus halodurans, GGCC
Bacillus halodurans, GCATC
Bacillus halodurans, GCATC
Bacteriodes,
```

The way I approached this is to create a list of tuples which will have the `organism name` and the `motif` together. I tried this using the `ElementTree` module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
rebase = tree.getroot()

list = []

for organisms in rebase.findall('Organism'):
        name = organisms.find('Name').text
        for each_organism in organisms.findall('Motif'):
            try:
                motif = organisms.find('Motif').text
                print name, motif
            except AttributeError:
                print name
```

However the output I get looks like this:

```
Bacillus halodurans, GGCC
Bacillus halodurans, GGCC
Bacillus halodurans, GGCC
```

Only the first `motif` gets recorded. This is my first time working with `ElementTree` so its slightly confusing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I don't need help with writing to a `CSV` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to fix is to replace:

```
motif = organisms.find('Motif').text
```

with:

```
motif = each_organism.text
```

You are already iterating through the `Motif` nodes inside an `Organism`. `each_organism` loop variable is holding a value of a `Motif` tag.

---

I would also change the variable names to avoid confusion. Also, I don't see the need for `try/except` inside the loop over `Motif` tags. In case there can be `name` tag missing, you can follow the "Ask for forgiveness, not permission" approach and catch the error:

```
for organism in rebase.findall('Organism'):
    try:
        name = organism.find('Name').text
    except AttributeError:
        continue

    for motif in organism.findall('Motif'):
        motif = motif.text
        print name, motif
```

Comment: Works like a charm. However at certain points in the file , an `organism` tag only has a `name` tag under it. In such cases i get the error that says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` at the line `name = organisms.find('Name').text`

Comment: @Beginner okay, I've updated the answer. As far as I understand, you want to skip the `Organism`s without names - for this I've used `continue` in the `except` block. Thanks.